# 16*16 Sudoku solver using backtracking in c

Tags: c, performance, backtracking, sudoku

I have coded a 16*16 sudoku solver using the backtracking algorithm in c. The program takes input from the user using a text file. The unfilled positions in the matrix are filled with a 0. Works perfectly fine.
I want to further optimize the code for time and space complexity. Please suggest some methods or ways to optimize the code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
#define N 16
int isAvailable(int sudoku[16][16], int row, int col, int num)                          
{
int i, j;
for(i=0; i<16; i++){

     if( (sudoku[row][i] == num) || ( sudoku[i][col] == num )  )
        return 0;
}

int rowStart = (row/4) * 4;
int colStart = (col/4) * 4;

for(i=rowStart; i<(rowStart+4); ++i)
{
    for(j=colStart; j<(colStart+4); ++j)
    {
        if( sudoku[i][j] == num )
            return 0;
    }
}    

return 1;
}    

int fillsudoku(int sudoku[16][16], int row, int col)                          
{
int i;
if( row<16 && col<16 )
{
    if( sudoku[row][col] != 0 ) 
    {
        if( (col+1)<16 )
            return fillsudoku(sudoku, row, col+1);
        else if( (row+1)<16 )
            return fillsudoku(sudoku, row+1, 0);
        else
            return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        for(i=0; i<16; ++i)
        {
            if( isAvailable(sudoku, row, col, i+1) )
            {
                sudoku[row][col] = i+1;

                if( (col+1)<16 )
                {
                   if( fillsudoku(sudoku, row, col+1) )
                       return 1;
                    else
                       sudoku[row][col] = 0;
                }
                else if( (row+1)<16 )
                {
                    if( fillsudoku(sudoku, row+1, 0) )    
                        return 1;
                    else
                        sudoku[row][col] = 0;
                }
                else
                    return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
else
{
    return 1;
}
} 

int main()
{
clock_t tic=clock(); 
int a,i,j;
int sudoku[N][N];
FILE *f;
f=fopen("s16.txt","r");


    for(i=0;i<N;i++){

        for(j=0;j<N;j++)
        {
            fscanf(f,"%d",&sudoku[i][j]);

        }
    }
if( fillsudoku(sudoku, 0, 0) )                                         
{

    for(i=0; i<16; ++i)
    {
        for(j=0; j<16; ++j){

            printf("%d ", sudoku[i][j]);
            if(sudoku[i][j]<10){

                printf(" ");
            }
            if(j%4==3){
                printf("|");
            }
        }
        printf("\n");
        if(i%4==3){         
        printf("----------------------------------------------------");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
else
{
    printf("\n\nNO SOLUTION\n\n");
}
clock_t toc=clock();
printf("\nTotal time elasped is %f", (double)(toc - tic) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
return 0;
fclose(f);
}
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be on the Code Review SE (as others noted).

Comment: @Biffen: Don't state to migrate to CR, if you are not sure the code is correct! OP should read their FAQ before migrating.

Comment: Off-topic, buit read the CR FAQ before migrating and format&indent the code properly.

Comment: @Biffen: They just don't like uncautions migration http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/5777/a-guide-to-code-review-for-stack-overflow-users . OP apparently ignored SO rules, too, so pointing him at the FAQ seems to be necessary.

Comment: I doubt You can improve space complexity. You can improve time though. Choosing boxes in order they appear in the matrix is far from optimal. You should choose box with least options available on every branching. Failing fast is the key.